# How to tar all directories in a directory to tar files named after tared directories

Tags: linux, tar

I want to tar all directories in a single directory to tar files named after themselves, so for example this directory of directories with tar-all.sh

```
dir___
      |- dirA
      |- dirB
      |- tar-all.sh
```

becomes

```
dir___
      |- dirA.tar.tgz
      |- dirB.tar.tgz
      |- tar-all.sh
```

Comment: Go ahead and post the code you've written so far, so we can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

for f in *
do
    echo "Creating tarball of $f..."
    tar -zcf $f.tar.gz $f
done
```

Results in:

```
> ./tar-all.sh
> Creating tarball of tar-all.sh...
> Creating tarball of dirA...
> Creating tarball of dirB...
> DONE!

  |- dirA.tar.tgz
  |- dirB.tar.tgz
  |- tar-all.sh.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will find and archive all the `dir` directory's subdirectories (deleting the original subdirectories).

```
for subdir in dir/*/; do
    dirname="$( basename "$subdir" )"
    ( cd "$dir" && tar -cz -f "$dirname.tgz" "$dirname" && rm -rf "$dirname" )
done
```

The pattern `dir/*/` will only match the pathnames of the subdirectories under `dir` and no non-directories, due to the `/` at the end.

Alternatively, using the `-C` option of `tar` instead of an explicit `cd`:

```
for subdir in dir/*/; do
    dirname="$( basename "$subdir" )"
    tar -cz -f "dir/$dirname.tgz" -C dir "$dirname" && rm -rf "$subdir"
done
```

Testing:

```
$ tree
.
`-- dir
    |-- a
    |   `-- file
    |-- b
    |   `-- file
    |-- c
    |   `-- file
    `-- complicated name
        `-- file

5 directories, 4 files
```

(run any of the two loops here)

```
$ tree
.
`-- dir
    |-- a.tgz
    |-- b.tgz
    |-- c.tgz
    `-- complicated name.tgz

1 directory, 4 files
```